# Cout unsigned char

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, cout, unsigned-char

I'm using *Visual Studio 2019*: why does this command do nothing?

```
std::cout << unsigned char(133);
```

It literally gets skipped by my compiler (I verified it using step-by-step debug):
I expected a print of `à`.
Every output before the next command is ignored, but not the previous ones. (`std::cout << "12" << unsigned char(133) << "34";` prints "12")

I've also tried to change it to these:

```
std::cout << unsigned char(133) << std::flush;
std::cout << (unsigned char)(133);
std::cout << char(-123);
```

but the result is the same.

I remember that it worked before, and some of my programs that use this command have misteriously stopped working... In a blank new project same result!

I thought that it my new custom keyboard layout could be the cause, but disabling it does not change so much.

On other online compilers it works properly, so may it be a bug of *Visual Studio 2019*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207391/discussion-on-question-by-foxel-cout-unsigned-char).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "sane" answer is: don't rely on extended-ASCII characters. Unicode is widespread enough to make this the preferred approach:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << u8"\u00e0\n";
}
```

This will explicitly print the character `à` you requested; in fact, that's also how your browser understands it, which you can easily verify by putting into e.g. some unicode character search, which will result in `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE`, with the code `U+00E0` which you can spot in the code above.

In your example, there's no difference between using a signed or unsigned char; the byte value 133 gets written to the terminal, but the way it interprets it might differ from machine to machine, basing on how it's actually set up to interpret it. In fact, in a UTF-8 console, this is simply a wrong unicode sequence (`u"\0x85"` isn't a valid character) - if your OS was switched to UTF-8, that might be why you're seeing no output.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! (even if it prints an Ã instead of an à) Where did you get that `u8"\xC3\xA0"` code? I would like to be able to change it for other characters...

Comment: @stacking There are numerous tables or search engines online (such as [this one](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex)), but it's really puzzling that you got the `Ã` character; makes me wonder if you actually do have an utf-8 capable terminal... It works as expected e.g. on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59be76f632d6572e).

Comment: I don't think I have a *UTF-8* capable terminal because Ã is non an *UTF-8* character, and as I said I could print *extended-ascii* characters until a couple of days ago

Comment: Solved! I had to write just `std::cout << "\xC3\xA0\n";` without `u8` (what does *u8* mean?)

Comment: @Foxel Could you dump both versions to a file `main > out.txt` and see what's inside those files? Preferrably with some hex dump utility.

Comment: As for `u8`, it denotes an UTF-8 encoded string literal (and since C++20, that also changes the type of the character to `char8_t`)

Comment: both `out << unsigned char(133);` and `out << static_cast<char>(133)` print **85** in hexadecimal (133 in decimal), while `out << "\u00e0";`, `out << "\xC3\xA0";` and `out << u8"\xC3\xA0";` print **C3A0** (out is a `std::ostream` object)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(133) << std::endl;
```

Or

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(133) << std::endl;
```

Since in mine all of this is working, it's hard to pinpoint the problem, the common sense would point to some configuration issue.

Comment: This won't help. The cast merely selects another `op<<` overload.

Comment: It's really not about "trying" here; it's about understanding what's happening and subsequently writing code to avoid such problems in the future. If you make a fix that you don't really understand, can you really guarantee that?

Comment: It doesn't work... It is just another way to make that same cast

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, your're right, but it's really hard to understand why some piece of code was working yesterday, is not today and works in the same compiler in a different machine, I'm all for understanding why things happen but this is a really strange one. If you have somenthing I'd really like to know.

Comment: @stacking, my hopes were low, but it was my best shot.